Why would ROS 2 TB3_Cartographer map well but slam_toolbox map is a mess?
Question: Why would turtlebot3_cartographer make good maps but slam_toolbox maps make a messy map?
Dist: ROS 2 Humble
Robot: GoPiGo3 Differential Drive
Lidar:  ydlidar X4  /scan  sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan
Odometry: /odom  nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
When I run
ros2 launch turtlebot3_cartographer cartographer.launch.py

and drive around, I get a nice map:

If I run the default slam_toolbox online_async config file, it will not generate a map at all, but when I run my online_async config file with the following changes:
$ diff params/my_mapper_params_online_async.yaml /opt/ros/humble/share/slam_toolbox/config/mapper_params_online_async.yaml 
4,6d3
<     # FILE:  my_mapper_params_online_async.yaml
<     # PURPOSE:  Mapping mode with base_frame changed to ROS 2 GoPiGo3 URDF files publishing base_link
< 
18,19c15
<     # base_frame CHANGED from base_footprint to base_link
<     base_frame: base_link
---
>     base_frame: base_footprint
20a17
>     use_map_saver: true
35c32
<     max_laser_range: 10.0 #for rastering images
---
>     max_laser_range: 20.0 #for rastering images


and the command:
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py 'slam_params_file:=./params/my_mapper_params_online_async.yaml'

I get a total mess:

